# Problem comparing items implementing IComparable

Tags: c#, generics, icomparable

I am working on a extension method where it finds the min item by specific selector. Below the code

```
    public static T MinBy<T, K>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, K> selector) where K : struct, IComparable, IConvertible
    {
        var min = default(K);
        T minItem = default(T);
        foreach (var item in src)
        {
            var current = selector(item);
            if (current < min)
            {
                min = current;
                minItem = item;
            }
        }

        return minItem;

    }
```

It gives error `Error Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'K' and 'K'`. But i have specified the generic  constraint K should be `Struct and IComparable`. I believe all the numeric data type can be satisfied with this.

Then how come this is a invalid operation.?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`IComparable` doesn't (and can't) say anything about operators. You should be using:

```
if (current.CompareTo(min) < 0)
```

Operators are static, and only ever *overloaded* rather than *overridden*. You can't require operators within interfaces, and the presence of a method doesn't magically change what an operator will do. (For example, overriding `Equals` does not change how `==` behaves.)

You should also note that as your constraint only talks about the nongeneric `IComparable` interface, you're going to be boxing at every operation. I would suggest you change the constraint to `IComparable<K>` instead. (Or drop the constraint and just use `Comparer<K>.Default` as Marc suggested.)

Some other comments about your method:

- If all of the key values are more than the default value for `K` (e.g. K=int and all the keys are positive) then you won't find an item
- You may wish to have an overload which accepts a particular `IComparare<K>` (but only if you drop the comparable constraint)
- There's no real need to constrain `K` to a value type. What if I wanted to find the person with the lexicographically earliest name?
- If there are no elements, it will return the default value for `T`; to fit in with the rest of LINQ I would suggest throwing `InvalidOperationException`
- I would suggest using `TSource` and `TKey` as the type parameters to be more consistent with LINQ

You may want to look at the [MoreLINQ MinBy implementation](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/3f59fd666af36598123d6201036e356ff915dd67/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) as an alternative. (Looking over that again, I'm not sure it's a good idea for us to require that `comparer` is non-null; it should probably use the default comparer in the same way as normal LINQ does if the comparer is null.)

Comment: *"For example, overriding `Equals` does change how `==` behaves"* - that should probably say "does **not** change"?

Answer (score 11):

`IComparable` doesn't provide *operator* support - you need to use `current.CompareTo(min)`. Or better, use `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(current,min)` - then you can drop the constraint *and* it'll handle nulls etc automatically, *and* it'll avoid boxing.

```
var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
...
// loop
    if(comparer.Compare(current, min) < 0) {...}
```