# Looking up values based on range data

Tags: c#, .net

What data structure or datatype would be good for holding data ranges, and return a value based on data that lies in that range?

For example suppose I have the following ranges

```
1-10 -> 1  
11-35 -> 2.5  
36-49-> 3.8  
50-60 -> 1.2  
61-80 -> 0.9
```

In this case given the number `41` I would want the number `3.8` returned (as 41 is between the ranges of 36 and 49).

Is there a clever way of representing such data in a datastructure in order to perform this lookup?

Comment: Have a look at [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) structures (maybe the latter is more appropriate for your problem)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343006/is-there-a-c-sharp-type-for-representing-an-integer-range

Answer (score 3):

A comparatively convenient and very performant implementation would be to use a `SortedList<int, Tuple<int, double>>`. Use the lower bound for each segment as the key and a tuple of upper bound + mapped value for the value:

```
var list = new SortedList<int, Tuple<int, double>>
{
    { 1, Tuple.Create(10, 1.0) },
    { 11, Tuple.Create(35, 2.5) },
};
```

(Of course you could decide to use a better-looking data structure to declare your parameters in order to enhance code maintainability and internally convert to this before getting down to business).

Since `list.Keys` is guaranteed to be sorted, when looking up a value you can use [binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2948872/50079) on it to find the index that is equal to or greater than your input value:

```
var index = list.Keys.BinarySearch(value);
if (index < 0 && ~index == 0) {
    // no match, stop processing
}
else if (index < 0) {
    // key not found as is, look at the previous interval
    index = ~index - 1;
}
```

At this point `index` points at the only range that might include `value`, so all that remains is to test for that:

```
if(x >= list.Keys[index] && x <= list.Values[index].Item1) {
    var result = list.Values[index].Item2;
}
else {
    // no match
}
```

You wouldn't call this "clean", but it's very short and very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

Key :

```
public class Interval<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public Nullable<T> Start { get; set; }
    public Nullable<T> End { get; set; }

    public Interval(T start, T end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public bool InRange(T value)
    {
        return ((!Start.HasValue || value.CompareTo(Start.Value) > 0) &&
                (!End.HasValue || End.Value.CompareTo(value) > 0));
    }
}
```

value : decimal

And you can use this Type : `Dictionary<Interval, decimal>`

Nota : you can define access methods

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while but I have a QuickAndDirty method which assumes all given values are valid and ranges are adjacent, without using any data structures.
And a very specific data structure which will only return something if the given index is exactly in the specified range and which can be expanded at run-time.

```
public abstract class TreeNode
{
    public static double QuickAndDirty(int index)
    {
        double result = 1.0;

        if (index > 10)
            result = 2.5;

        if (index > 35)
            result = 3.8;

        if (index > 49)
            result = 1.2;

        if (index > 60)
            result = 0.9;

        return result;
    }

    public abstract double GetValue(int index);

    public abstract TreeNode AddRange(int begin, int end, double value);

    public static TreeNode MakeTreePart(Tuple<int, int, double>[] ranges)
    {
        return TreeNode.MakeTreePart(ranges, 0, ranges.Length >> 1, ranges.Length - 1);
    }

    private static TreeNode MakeTreePart(Tuple<int, int, double>[] ranges, int min, int index, int max)
    {
        if (index == min || index == max)
            return new Leaf(ranges[index].Item1, ranges[index].Item2, ranges[index].Item3);

        return new SegmentTree(
            ranges[index].Item2 + .5,
            TreeNode.MakeTreePart(ranges, min, index >> 1, index - 1),
            TreeNode.MakeTreePart(ranges, index + 1, index << 1, max));
    }
}

public class SegmentTree : TreeNode
{
    private double pivot;
    private TreeNode left, right;

    public SegmentTree(double pivot, TreeNode left, TreeNode right)
    {
        this.pivot = pivot;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public override double GetValue(int index)
    {
        if (index < pivot)
            return left.GetValue(index);
        return right.GetValue(index);
    }

    public override TreeNode AddRange(int begin, int end, double value)
    {
        if (end < pivot)
            this.left = this.left.AddRange(begin, end, value);
        else
            this.right = this.right.AddRange(begin, end, value);
        // Do this to confirm to the interface.
        return this;
    }
}

public class Leaf : TreeNode
{
    private int begin, end;
    private double value;

    public Leaf(int begin, int end, double value)
    {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override double GetValue(int index)
    {
        if (index >= begin && index <= end)
            return value;
        throw new Exception("index out of range");
    }

    public override TreeNode AddRange(int begin, int end, double value)
    {
        if (this.end < begin)
            return new SegmentTree(((double)this.end + begin) * .5, this, new Leaf(begin, end, value));
        else if (end < this.begin)
            return new SegmentTree(((double)end + this.begin) * .5, new Leaf(begin, end, value), this);
        else throw new Exception("Indexes overlap.");
    }
}
    static void Main()
    {
        TreeNode start = new Leaf(36, 49, 3.8);
        start = start.AddRange(11, 35, 2.5);
        start = start.AddRange(1, 10, 1.0);
        start = start.AddRange(50, 60, 1.2);
        start = start.AddRange(61, 80, 0.9);
        double[] values = new double[70];
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
            values[i] = start.GetValue(i);

        TreeNode array = TreeNode.MakeTreePart(
            new Tuple<int, int, double>[]
            {
                Tuple.Create(1, 10, 1.0),
                Tuple.Create(11, 35, 2.5),
                Tuple.Create(36, 49, 3.8),
                Tuple.Create(50, 60, 1.2),
                Tuple.Create(61, 80, 0.9)
            });

        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
            values[i] = start.GetValue(i);
    }
```