# Why C# compiler can't understand generic arguments used in separate classes?

Tags: c#, generics

Here is my code:

```
public class Range<TNum> where TNum : IComparable
{
    public TNum From { get; set; }
    public TNum To { get; set; }
}

public class MarkableRange<TNum> where TNum : IComparable
{
    private readonly List<Range<TNum>> _markedRanges = new List<Range<TNum>>();

    public void MarkOne(TNum number)
    {
        _markedRanges.Where(r => number >= r.From && number <= r.To);
    }
}
```

compiler says that it cannot apply operator >= on operands in `number >= r.From` and `number <= r.To`

I could get away with `List<Tuple<TNum, TNum>>` but i wanted something more meaningful.
So is it me who did something wrong or c# compiler not that smart to understand my intention?

Comment: Ups, I probably was too quick about saying that Tuple would work here, looks like i have same issue with Tuple

Comment: See this Skeet answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101378/problem-comparing-items-implementing-icomparable/5101400#5101400. Also I suggest using `IComparable<TNum>` instead if just `IComparable`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TNum` is constrained to implement `IComparable`, which doesn't have the operators you're using (`<=` and `>=`). You should use the `CompareTo` method instead:

```
public void MarkOne(TNum number) {
  _markedRanges.Where(r => number.CompareTo(r.From) >= 0 && number.CompareTo(r.To) <= 0);
}
```

To use the operators, take a look [here](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/04/more-understandable-icomparable.html).

Also, prefer the generic `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Ok, that one threw me, I could have sworn those operators were overloaded for `IComparable`.

Comment: Unfortunately the operator overloading cannot be expressed on an interface.

Comment: Yeah, now I think about it, I'm thinking of the FxCop warning about overloading operators on anything that IMPLEMENTS it, not the interface itself. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182163%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: It's very mechanical and a lot of boilerplate code to follow that rule on all types that implement `IComparable`. I'd favor a different [strategy](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/04/more-understandable-icomparable.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can overload operators in C#, so you could define the >= and <= operators on your Range class that delegates to the IComparable implementation. Should work then.